# How can I get the count of rows using 'AND' and 'OR'?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I am trying to count rows that's satisfying the condition below:

`AND($K2<5,OR($M2>30,$N2>30),AND($O2<40,$P2<40))`

How do I use either SUMPRODUCT or COUNTIFS in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($K$2:$K$100<5)*(($O$2:$O$100<40)*($P$2:$P$100<40))*(($M$2:$M$100>30)+($N$2:$N$100>30)>0))
```

Comment: OMG That was fast and that works!! I have been trying to figure this out for hours. Thank you!

Comment: I understand the first part. But can you explain this part? Why >0 here? (($M$2:$M$100>30)+($N$2:$N$100>30)>0)

Comment: if we do not do the `>0` if both were true it would count as `2` not `1`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you for your help.